# Find images with specific pixel height/width and move them in another directory

Tags: command-line, macos, images

I want to find screenshot files, having a specific pixel height of 2220 and width of 1080, and want to move them into another folder. That's nothing I can do manually, as the source is 100+k images or so.

I've found the following command, but not able to bring it to work:

```
find /Users/myuser/Desktop/daten/JPG -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth {} | grep -E '2220‘ >/dev/null" \; -exec mv {} /Users/myuser/Desktop/screenshots \;
```

Error message:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: fixed the command and removed the blank in the folder name to:

```
find /Users/myuser/Desktop/daten/JPG8  -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c "sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth {} | grep '2220' >/dev/null" \; -exec mv {} /Users/myuser/Desktop/screenshots \;
```

.. but still not working well - no files have been moved.

Comment: `sips` runs in its own shell, when this shell is terminated its output `{}` is lost. Either use a tmpfile, export a variable or try to redefine your command.

Comment: You see that there are 2 different types of quotes: `grep -E '2220‘`

Comment: Could you help please, @paladin, to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question: I have managed to move and finally remove all screenshots with the following command:

```bsh
find ./JPG* -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c "sudo exiftool -csv -s -ImageSize {} | grep > /dev/null 'x2220'" \; -exec mv {} ./screenshots/ \;
```